# Element '<xpath expr="//field[@name=&#39;date_due&#39;]">' cannot be located in parent view

Tags: xml, odoo, odoo-11, odoo-15

I am upgrading a module that allows stock Picking From Customer/Supplier Invoice. This is a module downloaded for odoo11-community and i am performing an upgrade to be used in odoo15-enterprise.
Undfortunately, but i keep getting the error below:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Program Files\odoo-14\server\odoo\http.py", line 643, in _handle_exception
    return super(JsonRequest, self)._handle_exception(exception)
  File "C:\Program Files\odoo-14\server\odoo\http.py", line 301, in _handle_exception
    raise exception.with_traceback(None) from new_cause
odoo.tools.convert.ParseError: while parsing file:/c:/program%20files/odoo-14/server/odoo/addons/invoice_stock_move/views/invoice_stock_move_view.xml:4
Error while validating view:

Element '<xpath expr="//field[@name=&#39;date_due&#39;]">' cannot be located in parent view

View error context:
{'file': 'c:\\program '
         'files\\odoo-14\\server\\odoo\\addons\\invoice_stock_move\\views\\invoice_stock_move_view.xml',
 'line': 2,
 'name': 'Move Name',
 'view': ir.ui.view(1053,),
 'view.model': 'account.move',
 'view.parent': ir.ui.view(545,),
 'xmlid': 'customer_invoice_stock_move_view'}
```

HERE IS MY VIEW FILE

```
<odoo>
    <data>
        <record id="customer_invoice_stock_move_view" model="ir.ui.view">
        <field name="name">Move Name</field>
        <field name="model">account.move</field>
        <field name="inherit_id" ref="account.view_move_form"/>
        <field name="arch" type="xml">
            <xpath expr="//header" position="inside">
                <button name="action_stock_transfer" string="Transfer" type="object"  class="oe_highlight"
                     attrs="{'invisible':[('origin', '!=', False)]}"/>
            </xpath>
            <xpath expr="//field[@name='date_due']" position="after">
                <field name="picking_transfer_id"/>
                <field name="invoice_picking_id" invisible="1"/>
            </xpath>
            <xpath expr="//field[@name='number']" position="before">
                <div class="oe_button_box" name="button_box">
                    <button type="object"
                        name="action_view_picking" states="open,paid"
                        class="oe_stat_button" attrs="{'invisible':[('origin', '!=', False)]}"
                        icon="fa-truck">
                        <field name="picking_count"  string="Shipment" widget="statinfo"/>
                    </button>
                </div>
            </xpath>
        </field>
        </record>

        <record id="supplier_invoice_stock_move_view" model="ir.ui.view">
            <field name="name">Move Name</field>
            <field name="model">account.move</field>
            <field name="inherit_id" ref="account.view_move_form"/>
            <field name="arch" type="xml">
                <xpath expr="//header" position="inside">
                    <button name="action_stock_receive" string="Receive"  class="oe_highlight"
                            type="object"  attrs="{'invisible':[('origin', '!=', False)]}"/>
                </xpath>
                <xpath expr="//field[@name='date_due']" position="after">
                    <field name="picking_type_id"/>
                    <field name="invoice_picking_id" invisible="1"/>
                </xpath>
                <xpath expr="//field[@name='number']" position="before">
                    <div class="oe_button_box" name="button_box">
                        <button type="object"
                            name="action_view_picking"
                            class="oe_stat_button" attrs="{'invisible':[('origin', '!=', False)]}"
                            icon="fa-truck">
                            <field name="picking_count"  string="Shipment" widget="statinfo"/>
                        </button>
                    </div>
                </xpath>
            </field>
        </record>
  </data>
</odoo>
```

Can someone please point me in the right direction.

Comment: back office ? what's that

Comment: Back Office is the part of your web application which is  accessible by your company members ("Odoo Users") but not  by external visitors

Comment: So... In Main Dashboard > Settings > Technical Settings > Views, replace the id in your custom view URL by this id : 545, which is the id of the parent_view, as mentioned in the error message : 'view.parent': ir.ui.view(545,):

Comment: thanks for the clarity but im doing the upgrade in my local instance before i move it to the live server. Knowing this, is there another approach i could take at solving this issue?

Comment: Yes after having identified the PARENT view (id=545) using the method i have described (  /web?debug=1#id=545&action=28&model=ir.ui.view&view_type=form ) , you can find this view (account_move_view.xml ??)  probably in your local odoo-directory : srd/odoo/(oddo)/addons/account_move/views...

Answer (score 0):

In Back office : Main Dashboard > **Settings > Technical Settings > Views**, to access the parent view : replace the id in your custom view URL by this id : 545, which is the id of the parent_view, as mentioned in the error message : **'view.parent': ir.ui.view(545,)**:

Your  url should be similar to this one:

yourdomain.com **/web?#id=545&action=28&model=ir.ui.view&view_type=form**

And Check :

- whether the date_due field is existing in this parent view (id=545)
- whether the date_due field is inside a <t-if=...> scope